# Rendering with FFmpeg vs PNG formats

Tags: rendering

I've noticed while rendering with FFmpeg format, the rendering gets finished a lot quicker than in PNG, but I might be wrong. Which format should I use?

Answer (score 4):

**[FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg)** is not a format.
It is a suite of libraries and programs used to create files using different containers and codecs, used mostly for video files.

**[PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)** is a file format in which you can save images.

Which one to use depends on your needs.

Usually when creating animations or video it is recommended to render as an image sequence and encode to video later. That way, if the render stops or fails, you don't lose all of your work and you can try a different encoding and format until you find the one that works for you.

Comment: ok, but what about the speed? I tried rendering again, and it seems to be faster on FFmpeg, but now that you said about PNGs this seems like a safer way to do it. Shouldn't the render times for both be same?